# Can ansible ec2 module use iam role instead of aws_access_keys?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-iam

Normally, when we are using ansible ec2 module to do operations, it is like this:

```
- name: Creating ELB
  ec2_elb_lb:
    aws_access_key: "{{ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}"
    region: "{{ AWS_REGION }}"
    state: present
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
...
```

However, it will expose AWS Key pairs directly in source code. So I tried to attach IAM role to AWS EC2.

But I don't know how does ansible ec2 module use IAM role to get permissions to operate aws resources(such as create new ELB) if
   `aws_access_key: "{{ AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}"
 aws_secret_key: "{{ AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}"` are not passed to ec2 module.

Can anyone help me with this? How can I implement this function if using IAM role?

Comment: Yes, Ansible's AWS modules will use an IAM role if they can find one **attached to the instance they're executing on**.

Comment: @ceejayoz  Thanks for your reply. I've learned that, keys will be retrieved by following procedure: credentials --> environment variable --> instance metadata. Then, if my existing ec2 instance has already has ~.aws/credentials, should I delete it first in case ansible will read from it instead of its IAM role?

Comment: Please do not post [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48959063) on multiple StackExchange sites.

Comment: @user2896821 Yes, I'd remove the credentials file if you want it to use the role.

Comment: Yes, it should work as ansible usage boto and boto falls back to IAM role(of aws resource i.e your instance from where you are going to execute ansible ) if aws access/secret key not provided explicitly. Give it a try.